# Record succesive plots

Tags: r, plot, save

I do have a serie of plots that are displayed one by one within on of my treatment. To be able to see the next one, I have to press enter:

```
Hit <Return> to see next plot:
```

I have a huge serie of plots and I want to record all of them automatically. That is to say I dont want to press enter each time and I want to be able to call the `dev.copy()` function automatically after each plotting. Is there a way to do that?

Do a loop can do the trick ? Something like that:

```
for(i in length(number_of_plot)) {
Hit <Return>
dev.copy(png,'plot_number_[i]')
}
```

Of course, I cannot call Hit < Return > like that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the code you use to make the plots to get more details, you can try setting the *par(ask=FALSE)* so that R doesn't ask you to hit return to plot the next plot